# Is it good practice to pass a Python module as an argument

Tags: python, unit-testing, dependency-injection

I'm pretty new to python comming from Javaland. I'm writing a few modules and want to test them independently. Some of these have dependencies on functions defined in other modules. I want to find a light-weight way of injecting a test module when running the code from the test and use that instead of the real module that define those tests. I have come up with the pattern below as a means to achive that.

Say I have `somemodule.py` that define a function:

```
def aFunction:
    return _calculate_real_value_and_do_a_bunch_of_stuff()
```

In `foo.py` I have a class that depend on that function:

```
import somemodule

class Foo:
    def bar(self, somemodule=somemodule):
        return 'bar:' + somemodule.aFunction()
```

In test_foo.py:

```
import test_foo

def aFunction:
    return 'test_value'

class FooTest(unittest.TestCase:
    def test_bar(self):
        self.assertEquals('bar:test_value',somemodule.aFunction(test_foo))
```

**This works for injecting a module into Foo.bar, but is it good practice? Are there other, better ways of enabling testing of a module with dependencies?**

I find that the code is quite readable and I get the added benefit of a dependency list in the arguments to the function. The only downside I see is that I have an explicit dependency on `somemodule` in `foo.py` and from a dependency injection POV it might smell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual way to do this is via monkeypatching. Python lets you do this:

```
import somemodule
somemodule.aFunction = aFunction
```

and now from the perspective of `foo`, `somemodule.aFunction` is your test function. The [`mock` library](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/) has a `patch` decorator that does much the same thing but wraps it so that the original is restored when the test ends.

Comment: +1 for mock. Learned about it a few days ago and man has it changed my testing for the better.

Comment: This looks like a cleaner solution than my original one.